# mern project deployment on live ssl

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack, node-modules, mern

I want to deploy a mern project on ssl. Currently it is running on server with ip address but when I deploy it on ssl it is not running. It is working fine on http.
I have change on node modules transport-node and make it http to https.
1-I am using nginx as proxy server

When I deploy on ssl it give error:-

1-emitter.js?8a6f:50 OPTIONS https://privateIp:port/ net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

2-websocket.js?0f24:6 WebSocket connection to 'ws://privateip/sockjs-node/831/bocznd0p/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

3- your request is http,while it is require https.(handshake problem)